# Is God omnipotent?

Tags: nature-of-god, biblical-basis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Biblical evidence for omnipotence/omniscience](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2643/biblical-evidence-for-omnipotence-omniscience)

<sub>Next in my [line of questions](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2996/is-god-omniscient)...</sub>

I've always heard silly questions like "Could God create a rock so big he couldn't lift it?"  Obviously there's multiple mistaken assumptions in there.  However, there is one assumption in there that fits with my understanding of God:  **that He is omnipotent.**

However, I realized that I've been believing this without any biblical backing for this.  So, I pose the question here.

What is the biblical basis for the omnipotence of God?  Is God truly all-powerful or are there limits to his abilities?

Clearly, he parted the Red Sea, stopped the waters of the Jordan River when it was at flood stage, and stopped the spinning of the earth so that a war could wage on.  However, what are the limitations of this power?

Is he truly omnipotent?  (And does that even mean that he can do absolutely anything he wants?)

Comment: I've always heard it described as anything that is possible. So things that aren't paradoxical. So, God couldn't create something that is simultaneously the hardest and softest substance to the same hand touching it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

God Himself asks this question, apparently rhetorically:

> [Jeremiah 32:27](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Jeremiah%2032:27&version=NIV1984)
>
> I am the LORD, the God of all mankind. **Is anything too hard for me?**

Implication: yes, God is all powerful.

Comment: "Is anything too hard for me?" on its own is not very convincing - it's a question, not a statement.