# Are there any verses showing God being fooled or deceived?

Tags: nature-of-god, omniscience

Are there any passages in the bible (old or new) that display god as getting tricked by somebody? For example in the Garden of Eden God didn't know (or seemed to not know) about the apple being eaten until he was told. Could they have lied? Are there any examples of something like this happening?

Comment: Related: [Why is God asking questions...](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3004/11471)

Comment: Welcome to C.SE! When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). This isn't a bad question, but it isn't a great one. I'm not VTC because it is a valid question - but the interpretation that God "didn't know" what Adam was up to seems like a literal reading that wouldn't be common.  I'll leave that to an answerer to address.

Comment: @kilrizzy I rolled back your edit because the question body isn't the right place to explain why you accepted the answer you did. You don't need to explain that answer actually, but if you really want to then a comment on that answer would be the best place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, else the following would make no sense:

**Genesis 3:8 NIV**

> They heard the sound of the LORD God walking in the garden in the cool
>   of the day, and the man and his wife hid themselves from the presence
>   of the LORD God among the trees of the garden.

**Genesis 32:27**

> So He said to him, “What is your name?”

**1 Kings 19:9**

> And there he went into a cave, and spent the night in that place; and
>   behold, the word of the Lord came to him, and He said to him, “What
>   are you doing here, Elijah?”

**Mark 5:30**

> And Jesus, immediately knowing in Himself that power had gone out of
>   Him, turned around in the crowd and said, “Who touched My clothes?”

If God knew the answers, he wouldn't have asked.  Therefore, he could have been given the incorrect answer.  Alternatively, God continues to test people by asking questions that he already knows the answer to - which doesn't really fit.  He would be the master of the art of rhetorical questions.

Comment: This doesn't match any theology I know of.  Arguably the last example is God taking on human weakness, but I would think the most natural way to take the earlier examples is as rhetorical.

Comment: @ChrisSunami I disagree, the most unnatural way to take the questions would be rhetorical.  "What is your name?" sounds like a genuine question. etc.

Comment: It might help this as an answer if you would state whether this is your own opinion versus if any major religious group or thinker endorses this interpretation.

Comment: Jesus was not omniscient in the same sense normally applied to God the Father. The 1 Kings passage doesn't imply lack of knowledge on God's part. many humans ask "What are you doing here?" when they know the answer perfectly well.

Comment: Those verses all make total sense if God, who knows all things but who desires to relate to his people, takes a loving pause to allow people who have done wrong a chance to explain themselves. Those are words that a loving parent will ask o the child with crumbs in his mouth and a missing cookie, in order to let the child admit and confess.  God knew what happened. He wanted to know if we knew what we did, and were willing to come clean about it

Comment: Chris Sunami's answer is what mainstream Christianity would want to hear.  I argue that the scriptures reflect differently as noted - which is fine, we all do not have to agree.  Arguing and "wrestling" with God was part of the Jewish tradition which would imply that his mind can be changed and therefore can be fooled or deceived.  Furthermore, wasn't God fooled or deceived at the fall of Satan?  I'm pretty sure he didn't plan the rebellion.

Comment: `<soapbox>` Sometimes we want to believe what our "doctrine" says so much that we make patterns to make the illogical and inconspicuous fit. `</soapbox>`

Answer (score 3):

In standard Christian theology, God is described as [omniscient](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/omniscience/), or all-knowing (by major theologians such as St Aquinas).  This is incompatible with being deceived.  Accordingly we would not interpret any passage in the Bible as implying God was deceived, unless we wished to discard this core belief.

Answer (score 1):

God is cannot be deceived.

> Be not deceived; God is not mocked: for whatsoever a man soweth, that shall he also reap. *Galatians 6:7*
>
> For the wisdom of this world is foolishness with God. For it is written, He taketh the wise in their own craftiness. *1 Corinthians 3:19*
>
> Shall not God search this out? for he knoweth the secrets of the heart. *Psalms 44:21*
>
> And he said unto them, Ye are they which justify yourselves before men; but God knoweth your hearts: for that which is highly esteemed among men is abomination in the sight of God. *Luke 16:15*

The Bible is very clear that **God can't be deceived**. It is impossible to deceive God.

Comment: I was just about to put in Galatians 6:7.  This is a better answer than what I would have done though :)

Answer (score 0):

I would second what Chris Sunami has said and would like to add up couple of scriptures

1 Corinthians 1:25 King James Version (KJV)
25 Because the foolishness of God is wiser than men; and the weakness of God is stronger than men.

1 Corinthians 3:19 King James Version (KJV)
19 For the wisdom of this world is foolishness with God. For it is written, He taketh the wise in their own craftiness.

However smart, brilliant, wise and crafty a man can be, he never stands equal to God Almighty.